# Channels django nginx 502

Tags: django, nginx, django-channels, http-status-code-502

I ran into a problem once I install and add "channels" to the settings and after that to the asgi file. Server crashes, I get 502 and nginx won't start. How can I add these channels and start working already

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "mysite.asgi.application"

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
"http": get_asgi_application(),
# Just HTTP for now. (We can add other protocols later.)
# WebSocket chat handler
"websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
    URLRouter([
        
    ])
),
```

})

help, I'm sure a lot of people have come across this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you configure Nginx properly? Below is a sample Nginx config.

```
upstream channels-backend {
    server localhost:8000;
}
...
server {
    ...
    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }
    ...
    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_pass http://channels-backend;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
    ...
}
```

See the deployment guide here: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html